# The value is not added in case the array is empty

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which is supposed to read a list of domains from a txt file, find its IP and find its open ports using Nmap and write three of them to a .csv file. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# cache maps from IP addresses to open ports
declare -A cache

getports() {
    local ip=$1
    nmap -v -Pn -p 1-100 "$ip" -oG - \
        | awk -F '\t' '
            /Ports:/ {
                n = split($2, a, /,? /)
                printf "%s", a[2]
                for (i = 3; i <= n; ++i)
                    printf ":%s", a[i]
            }
        '
}

{
    echo 'Name,IP,Port'

    while IFS= read -r url; do
        # Read filtered dig output into array
        readarray -t ips < <(dig +short "$url")

        # Build array of open ports
        unset ports
        for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
            ports+=("${cache["$ip"]:=$(getports "$ip")}")
        done

        # Output
        printf '%s,%s,%s\n' \
            "$url" \
            "$(IFS='-'; echo "${ips[*]}")" \
            "$(IFS='-'; echo "${ports[*]}")"
    done < URLs.txt
} > myFile.csv
```

The problem is that sometimes Nmap doesn't return any result. In this case, I want to append the `None` value to the `ports` array, so I added this piece of code before `#Output` part:

```
if [ ${#ports[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
      ports+=("none")
fi
```

but it seems that it doesn't work and this value is not added to the third column of my .csv file (the corresponding field of the third column becomes empty). What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easiest if you didn't try to do so much in a single statement, just write all the `if` statements.

```
    for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
        if [ -z "${cache["$ip"]}" ]; then
            p=$(getports "$ip")
            ports+=("${p:=None}")
            cache["$ip"]=$p
        else 
            ports+=("${cache["$ip"]}")
        fi
    done
```

Comment: but it didn't add "none" to empty fields! It added a `}` to the end all the values in the third column (whether they are empty or not)

Comment: I had an extra `}` after `$(getports "$ip")`

Comment: The extra `}` was removed, but the problem of not appending `none` still exists

Comment: I tested it and I got `None` when the function returns an empty result.